# PHP/MySQL query isn't working

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I'm trying to a add a tire to a database of tires from a form. If I use a var_dump, the query is right, but it isn't inserting anything into the database. Here is my code.

```
 <?php

require('../includes/database_connection.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    $idtires = '';
   $size = $_POST["size"];
 $idbrand = $_POST["idbrand"];
$price = $_POST["price"];
$mileage = $_POST["mileage"];
$idterrain = $_POST["idterrain"];
$idvehicle = $_POST["idvehicle"];
$idtiremodel = $_POST["idtiremodel"];

function add_tire($idtires, $size,  $idbrand, $price, $mileage, $idterrain,     $idvehicle, $idtiremodel) {
     global $db;
     $query = "INSERT INTO tires
                  (idtires, size, idbrand, price, mileage, idterrain, idvehicle, idtiremodel)
               VALUES
                  ($idtires, '$size',  '$idbrand','$price', '$mileage', '$idterrain', '$idvehicle', '$idtiremodel')";
   var_dump($query);
   // var_dump($db); 
     $db->exec($query);

}


  add_tire($idtires, $size, $idbrand, $price, $mileage, $idterrain, $idvehicle, $idtiremodel);



include('add.php');

?>
```

HERE IS ADD.PHP form:

```
<table>

            <form method='post' action='addatire.php' name='addform' id='addform'>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>
                            <label for='size'>Size:</label><br />
                        </p>
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <p>
                            <input type='text' name='size' required value="<?php echo(isset($size['size'])); ?>"/>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>
                            <label for='idbrand'>Brand ID:</label><br/>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                     <td>
                        <p>
                        <input type='text' name='idbrand' required value="<?php echo(isset($idbrand['idbrand'])); ?>"/>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>
                            <label for='price'>Price:</label><br/>
                        </p></td>
                    <td><p>
                            <input type='text' name='price' required value="<?php echo(isset($price['price'])); ?>"/>
                        </p></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>
                            <label for='mileage'>Mileage:</label><br/>
                        </p></td>
                      <td><p>
                            <input type='text' name='mileage' required value="<?php echo(isset($mileage['mileage'])); ?>"/>
                        </p></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>
                            <label for='idterrain'>Terrain ID:</label><br/>
                        </p></td>
                     <td><p>
                            <input type='text' name='idterrain' required value="<?php echo(isset($idterrain['idterrain'])); ?>"/>
                        </p></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                  <td>
                        <p>
                            <label for='idvehicle'>Vehicle ID:</label><br/>
                        </p></td>
                     <td><p>
                            <input type="text" name="idvehicle" required value="<?php echo(isset($idvehicle['idvehicle'])); ?>"/>

                        </p></td>
                  </tr>

                 <tr>
                     <td>
                        <p>
                            <label for='idtiremodel'>Tire Model ID:</label><br/>
                        </p></td>
                    <td><p>
                            <input type="text" name="idtiremodel" required value="<?php echo(isset($idtiremodel['idmodel'])); ?>"/>

                        </p></td>
                </tr>



                 <tr>
                      <td><p>
                            <input type="submit" name="action" value="Add A Tire"/>

                        </p></td>
                 </tr>
             </form>
          </table>



                    <?php echo get_tires(); ?>
                 </div>


?>
```

HERE is the database connection:

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "localhost" OR $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "127.0.0.1") {
        // login locally
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=?';
        $username = ?;
        $password = ?;

 } else {
        // login online
         $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=?';
           $username = '?';
         $password = '?';

    }

    try {
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $error_message = $e->getMessage();
        include('database_error.php');
        exit();

    }
?>
```

My usernames and passwords aren't really ? though, I'm just using those here for the sake of privacy and safety.

Comment: post the content of ../includes/database_connection.php your  $db->exec($query); is not working

Comment: Why aren't you checking the return values of your calls to your database for errors? You're also susceptible to SQL injection here.

Comment: I'm in the middle of developing. It's not the finished product. The database connection has my passwords and it is working fine with other functions that do similar things. Other functions (just like this one) work with the database.

Comment: As I've looked over your code my gut tells me that maybe problem is with $db. If $db is defined in database_connection then a redefinition add_tire maybe is problem. If $db is not defined in include then it has to be of course initialized before it can be used or php trows exception.

Comment: var_dump of $db = object(PDO)#1 (0) {} which is what it should say, right?

Comment: @Regina It's during the development period that you're most in need of decent error reporting.

Comment: @HoboSapiens, I'm not sure what you mean. I'm a learner, so please tell me what you mean exactly. I'm checking everything I know to check

Comment: @Regina Calls to MySQL fail silently, returning only an error condition that you have to check for. (PDO allows you to choose to throw an exception but your code doesn't do that). You should be checking the return value of every database call for `false`, and if you find it, check the appropriate property or function call for error information. You currently don't know why this code is failing. It's likely that there's an unchecked error that will tell you. See the [PDO Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) for details on `PDO::errorCode` and `PDO::errorInfo`

Comment: Could you give me an example of this so I know where to begin?

Comment: @HoboSapiens, if you would put your answer as a answer I would mark it as the answer to my question. Thank you. And God bless you for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting an error on your insert and just not seeing it:

```
$db->exec($query) or die(print_r($db->errorInfo(), true));
```